# Firestore data structure and rules for multi organisation, multi user setup with variable roles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm quite new to NoSQL and Firebase/firestore in general (I have a strong background in traditional SQL however), so whilst I'm understanding most of the basics regarding options for data structure and how to create rules to manage read/write permissions etc, I'm having a hard time coming up with an 'elegant' solution to this in regards to data structure and simplicity of the client-side rules I'll be using. A key point is I'm trying to negate the need for any get() reads in the rules, which due to financial implications, I'm trying to avoid...

I'm writing an e-commerce related SaaS products where...

The app will have multiple private 'organisations' that are only visible to users that have these organisations assosiated with them.
The app will have multiple users, who can, in turn have access varying levels of access to multiple organisations. For e.g, a user may be a 'user' on one organisation and an 'admin' of another.
Each user will have a variable number of 'roles', in the form of such things as 'products.read', 'products.write', 'orders.read', 'order.write' etc etc

I started with a hierachy of products etc that all fall under a root 'organisation' collection and I have custom claims added to each user in the format of {"orgs": ["12345"]}... but I'm stuck on the permissions/roles side. I figured I could add a 'permissions' or 'access' collection to the organisation top level where the UID is the key and each role that a user may have would be under this ID... but that gave me only one option when it comes to the rules side of things. I'd have to use the get() function and thus I'd have to double spend for each access check as that would trigger another read.

Does anybody have any insight into a possible solution to this that doesn't require an inner get()? I'm sure this is a common pattern/problem, but I've come up short when googling and I guess my head is not in the right place at the moment so figured I'd reach out :)

Many thanks

Comment: Questions on SO are code specific; write some code and when you get stuck, post it and we'll take a look. This is more of an app design question and really, it's kinda vague. For example - *gave me only one option when it comes to the rules side of things* - Why is that limited to one option? Rules are very flexible and can take many things into consideration. For example; a users collection has each user as a document; within each user document a property could exist that stores each company they are part of and what "role" they have. What code is triggering reads? What/why is an "inner get"?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Jay, but I didn't find anything in the rules specifying I'm not allowed to ask such a question. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I'm not asking about a code issue, sure, but I'm asking about a specific problem relating to Firestore, which I believe is a topic that people may discuss here. I'm sure any discussion of this particular problem will result in useful content for other readers in future, but perhaps there's a better place for me to ask my question?

Comment: I understand and perhaps my comment was not clear. You can ask anything you want, however, app design questions are difficult to answer without understanding the entire use case. They often require additional data and SO is a terrible chat room. More importantly, the question is also a bit vague about the issues being described. See my above comment for examples. There's absolutely no reason you can't do what you're asking and costs would be minimum. We also don't know why an 'inner get()' is needed as that should not be the case with correct code implementation. More clarity would help.

Comment: I'm not asking about application or data design per se (though it would have implications), but specifically about the Firestore rules system and how it can be leveraged to provide a very specific set of rules to provide the behaviour that I described in my question. Sam did a great job of providing a possible solution and seemed to understand what I was asking, but it was my hope that this could be done without additional calls to the get() lookup function, but I'm starting to realise that perhaps without a far more verbose data structure, it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: While @samthecodingman answer is great, it may be way more complex than is needed. What about implementing what I suggested above; a property that contains the companies they are authorized with as a key and their access level as a value. Rules can simply check that; if the company doesn't exist, then no access. If it does, the value determines the access level. It's one rule read of the user document = almost $0 cost. The fact your code only gave one option sounds like the structure/code/rules are not set up for the use case, but that's just a guess without more info.

Answer (score 2):

As you have identified, storing relevant roles in a organisation-based user document (such as `/organisations/{orgId}/privateUserData/{userId}`) will offer one of the best solutions.

At the time of writing, Firestore pricing is $0.06c (USD) per 100,000 document reads (above the 50k/day free quota). Securing your data using one `get()` call in your rules, with all the relevant data needed being in `/organisations/{orgId}/privateUserData/{userId}`, would make the rate $0.06c (USD) per 50,000 secured document reads at worst.

What do you mean "at worst"? As long as you aren't reading documents 1-by-1 (e.g. directly by their id), you won't actually pay for these secured document reads at a 1:1 rate. If your query returns 100 documents in one go, you only pay for the 1 `get()` call as the result of that call is cached and reused for all validations in that query.

---

To apply that with an example, let's assume you are using a document optimized for ease of use that looks like:

```json
/organisations/{orgId}/privateUserData/{userId}: {
  uid: "<userId>", // for collection group queries targetting a particular user
  orgId: "<orgId>", // for collection group queries targetting a particular organisation
  disabled: false, // for suspending users,
  roles: {
    "products.read": true,
    "products.write": false, // can also omit, as rules will assume false
    // ...
  },
  userProfile: { // duplication of data in NoSQL databases is common
    img: "https://...",
    displayName: "Example User",
    username: "exampleuser"
  }
}
```

We can then wire it up with these rules:

```json
service cloud.firestore {
  // note: this is not JavaScript - it is Security Rules Language

  // True if the user is signed in, they exist in the organisation, and are not marked disabled
  function isActiveOrgMember(orgId) {
    return request.auth.uid != null
      && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organisations/$(orgId)/privateUserData/$(request.auth.uid)).data.get("disabled", false) != true;
  }
  
  // True if the signed in user has the named role for the given organisation,
  // expected to be called after isActiveOrgMember(orgId) has returned true.
  function hasOrgRole(orgId, permission) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organisations/$(orgId)/privateUserData/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.get(permission, false)
  }
 
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organisations/{orgId} {
      // Any member can read the org details
      allow read: if isActiveOrgMember(orgId);

      // Only admins can update org details
      allow write: if isActiveOrgMember(orgId) && hasOrgRole(orgId, "orgadmin");

      match /privateUserData/{userId} {
        // Only the named user (along with org admins) can read their own data
        allow read: if isActiveOrgMember(orgId)
                    && (request.auth.uid == userId
                    || hasOrgRole(orgId, "orgadmin"));

        // Only org admins can update a user's data (the Admin SDKs
        // can also make changes because they bypass security rules)
        // TODO: Add data validation (e.g. admins should not be able
        // edit userProfile data)
        allow write: if isActiveOrgMember(orgId)
                     && hasOrgRole(orgId, "orgadmin");
      }

      match /products/{productId} {
        // Any active member can read products documents if they have
        // the appropriate roles
        allow read: if isActiveOrgMember(orgId)
                    && (hasOrgRole(orgId, "products.read")
                    || hasOrgRole(orgId, "orgadmin"));
        // Any active member can write to products documents if they
        // have the appropriate roles
        // TODO: Add data validation (e.g. certain keys should be present)
        allow write: if isActiveOrgMember(orgId)
                    && (hasOrgRole(orgId, "products.write") || hasOrgRole(orgId, "orgadmin"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above setup:

- a read of `/organisations/{orgId}/privateUserData/{userId}` directly will incur a document read cost of 1. This is because the `get()` call is checking the same document being read and thus just returns the document as-is.
- a read of `/organisations/{orgId}` directly will incur a document read cost of 2. This is because the `get()` call needs to fetch the user's document.
- a read of `/organisations/{orgId}/products/{productId}` directly will also incur a document read cost of 2. This is because the `get()` call still needs to fetch the user's document.
- a list query of the top 100 products under `/organisations/{orgId}/products` will incur a document read cost of up to 101. At best, it will only cost 1 document read for the roles check that it uses to fail the query. At worst, it will cost 101 document reads - 1 for the roles check and 1 for each returned document.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response, Sam.

It is a very good point RE the cost - I guess it just bugs me that with some currently-unknown tweak to the schema, I could potentially half the cost of each read. I think the subscription price should more than cover any concerns there - it's just the perfectionist in me wants to solve the 'problem'.

Perhaps this is a case of early optimisation paralysis - I guess I just work on getting it going first and if there's a suitable 'fix' in future, I can handle it then :)

Thanks very much for your insight and going to the extra mile.